weighted average from two table in mysql
i have two tables :
-items(id,quantity,price)
-entry_voucher(quantity,price,id_table1)
i want to calculate weighted average for every record in entry_voucher and update price in table items
i have tried boucles but its too long code i want to make it with sql

What does "weighted" mean? Please provide both sample data and expected result in your question, show what you have tried, explain what you need to know.

Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve].

What column(s) of what table do you want to average? What weights do you want to use? Which price do you want to update?  Are you sure you need to perform updates at all, as opposed to computing the desired weighted averages on demand?

"i want to make it with sql" - so why the [tag:java] tag ?

@JonasMetzler hi thanks for answer , the average is : ((old!quantity * old_price ) + (new_quantity*new_price)) / old_quantity + new_quantity

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm sorry, but this question needs more details for us to be able to understand what you are asking. To better understand how to use Stack Overflow, I suggest browsing with the Tour as a starting point. Include the Help Center and How to Ask a Good Question. Then edit the question.

Please reread the 1s comment: It is a request that you edit the question. The question should better explain what you are trying to do, include code of your attempt, and include examples. An example should include data and expected result. With the explanation, we should be able to understand, for each example, how the expected results should be obtained from the data. As it stands now, your comment reply to @JonasMetzler made things more confusing, because we don't know what old_quatity, old_price, new_quantity and new_price are and how the relate to what you've shown for the tables.

Not sure that I fully understand your goal, but this query can help to to understand the principle:
UPDATE items
SET price = (
    SELECT SUM(ev.quantity * ev.price) / SUM(ev.quantity)
    FROM entry_voucher ev
    WHERE ev.id_table1 = items.id
    GROUP BY ev.id_table1
);

This SQL query selects each entry in items and updates its price to the weighted average of price from entry_voucher (weighted by quantity). The GROUP BY clause groups the sum by the id_table1, making sure that each item's price is calculated based on its related rows in entry_voucher.

@Aliaksel vasilkou hi thanks for your interessting answer , the average is : ((old!quantity * old_price ) + (new_quantity*new_price)) / old_quantity + new_quantity
